# MYSQL statement not doing anything

Tags: php, mysql

The query im using it to insert a few pieces of data into a table called "purchases" Ive got a session variable that holds the username of the person currently logged in called "login_user" the other pieces of data are all instantiated in the previous page:

This is the code that i currently have:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>View shopping cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
<body>


<br>
<div id="books-wrapper">

<!-- #content to center the menu -->
<div id="content">
<!-- This is the actual menu --> 
<ul id="darkmenu">
      <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="catalogue.php">Catalogue</a></li>
      <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href= "view_cart.php">Cart</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Orders</a></li>
</ul>

<div id = "welcome" >
Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['login_user']?>! <br> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</div>

    </div>

<br><br>
 <h1 id = "mainHeader" >View Cart</h1>
 <br>
 <div class="view-cart">
    <?php
$current_url = base64_encode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(isset($_SESSION["books"]))
{
        $total = 0;
        echo '<form method="post" action="">';
        echo '<ul>';
        $cart_items = 0;
        foreach ($_SESSION["books"] as $cart_itm){
            $ISBN = $cart_itm["ISBN"];
            $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT Title,BookDesc,Price FROM books WHERE ISBN='$ISBN'");
            $obj = $results->fetch_object();

            echo '<li class="cart-itm">';
            echo '<span class="remove-itm"><a href="cart_update.php?removep='.$cart_itm["ISBN"].'&return_url='.$current_url.'">×</a></span>';
            echo '<div class="p-Price">'.$currency.$obj->Price.'</div>';
            echo '<div class="book-info">';
            echo '<h3>'.$obj->Title.' (ISBN :'.$ISBN.')</h3> ';
            echo '<div class="p-quantity">Quantity : '.$cart_itm["quantity"].'</div>';
            echo '<div>'.$obj->BookDesc.'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</li>';
            $subtotal = ($cart_itm["Price"]*$cart_itm["quantity"]);
            $total = ($total + $subtotal);

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_name['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->Title.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_code['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$ISBN.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_desc['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$obj->BookDesc.'" />';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity['.$cart_items.']" value="'.$cart_itm["quantity"].'" />';
            $cart_items ++;
                            }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '<span class="check-out-txt">';
        echo '<strong>Total : '.$currency.$total.'</strong>  ';
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<button name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Save Order</button>';
        echo '</form>';

         if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `purchases` (`OrderNo`,`BookName`,`Quantity`,`TotalPrice`,`ISBN`,`StudentID`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $obj->Title . "', '" . $cart_itm['quantity'] . "', '" . $total . "', '" . $ISBN . "', '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "');";
    }


}


?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue im having is that when the user clicks on the "save order" button nothing happens. No data is inserted into the database.

Ive echoed out the variables to check if they hold the data i want and that seems to work, but the insert statement doesnt seem to do anything

Any ideas?

Comment: you didn't do __ANYTHING__ with the sql!

Comment: seems like you are just loading query in to "$sql" variable. Where you execute this query. use echo mysqli_errno($quryVar);  to get actual error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `purchases` (`OrderNo`,`BookName`,`Quantity`,`TotalPrice`,`ISBN`,`StudentID`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $obj->Title . "', '" . $cart_itm['quantity'] . "', '" . $total . "', '" . $ISBN . "', '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "');";    
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: inside this if block:          if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `purchases` (`OrderNo`,`BookName`,`Quantity`,`TotalPrice`,`ISBN`,`StudentID`) VALUES (NULL, '" . $obj->Title . "', '" . $cart_itm['quantity'] . "', '" . $total . "', '" . $ISBN . "', '" . $_SESSION['login_user'] . "');";
    }

Comment: Looks like you're missing a ; there:  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql); $stmt->execute();

Answer (score 0):

You have only button at the form's end, the script doesn't know you want it to be the submit button.

Change

```
echo '<button name="submit_btn" class="save_order">Save Order</button>';
```

to

```
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="Save Order" />';
```

Also when you submit, you only define `$sql` string, you need to `$mysqli_query` it.

Comment: Hi, that hasnt changed anything

Answer (score -2):

```
    echo '<form method="post" action="">';
```

action is void, must have an url like "/index.php"